# Encode base3 using bit values

Tags: c, encode, radix

So i've to convert base 10 to base 3. Thats pretty simple. For instance i've 16 in base 10 which is 121 in base 3.

I've made a simple algorithm that can convert to base 3 from base 10. But here comes to the problem. The assignments says that, I need to store the base 3 number using 2 bits. Therefore 121 will be 011001. Not sure how i should implemented this in C.

00 : 0 
01 : 1 
11 : 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your representation for base 10?

Comment: Multiply by 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Just regular, for instance: Input: 16(base10); Output: 011001.

Comment: "Not sure how i should implemented this" is fairly broad.  What part of the task is unclear?  Try posting code for as much as you know.

Comment: And post also the text of the assignment, maybe then it will me more clear to us what you want.

Comment: "I've made a simple algorithm that can convert to base 3 from base 10." --> post that missing algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a "do my homework" site.

Comment: Note that your coding of 121 base 3 is claimed to be 011001 binary, but your table of binary encodings indicates it should be 011101.  You should fix this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own type and then store the bits in a union

```
typedef struct {
      unsigned int bits : 2;
} DIGIT;

union int_b3 {
    DIGIT digits[8];
    // manipulate all together
    int raw;
}

// create number
int_b3 my_number;

// Set individual digits
my_number.digits[0].bits = 1;

// Process the number all together
my_number.raw <<= 2;
```

Comment: Point. Updated types- was trying to emphasize more structures